# How can I set custom Google Cloud Logging labels with gcloud CLI

Tags: google-cloud-logging

I want to set custom labels for log entries with Google Cloud Logging written by `gcloud`. The docs state that it should be possible to customize the structure of the payload by providing the full LogEntry.

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging#use-gcloud

Here is something I tried, but did not work:

```bash
gcloud logging write my-log --payload-type=json '{
  "logName": "projects/my-project/logs/my-log",
  "resource": {
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "my-project"
      }
  },
  "severity": "WARNING",
  "labels": {
    "mylabel": "mylabel"
  },
  "jsonPayload": {"message": "My Text Payload"}
}'
```

Here is also a post from the Google Issue Tracker were someone asks for something similar, setting the resource type, and someone else answered that it should be possible now: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120463357.

Answer (score 0):

The one which you are referring to in the case seems to be a different issue, that issue is related to setting the resource type, whereas you are facing challenges while creating custom labels in the log entries. Since the feature doesn't exist altogether there is no possibility for making configurations based on using the gcloud CLI.   
There seems to be a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228349814) created recently for this issue and the GCP product team has acknowledged it, go through the issue request and follow/star it for more updates. For your information as per the [support docs](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), giving stars to a feature request makes the team work on this feature request on priority.

**Update:**
Changed the feature request link as there seems to be two different feature requests with slight differences. One is on creating the custom labels and the other is on viewing the custom labels.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is the link for the feature request correct? It seems like it is more about showing and filtering on a custom label.

Comment: @p13rr0m I have updated the feature request link there seems to be two different feature requests with slight difference

Comment: @p13rr0m have you got enogh time to go through the attached FR, revert back if you are still facing some issues

Comment: @p13rr0m have you happened to go through the feature request and we are happy to address any other queries, revert back here

Comment: Hi, yes I had the chance to go through the feature request, but I don't see the connection between my question and the request. I am thinking about making a custom request with `curl` or using the Python client libraries.

Comment: @p13rr0m currently there is no possibility for setting custom labels in the cloud logging or for filtering the content based on custom labels in cloud logging either by using clients or directly. The title `Audit logs are not having custom labels` of the feature request explains the same.